# Tomcat 8 Fav Icon cannot be replaced

Tags: css, tomcat, tomcat8

I am beginner so take it easy on me.
Recently i have developed a web application in java and i have deployed it on `Tomcat7` and it worked fine but when i deploy it on `Tomcat8` the default fav icon cannot be replaced although i am using the following:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/url/logo.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/url/logo.png">`
And the browser locates the photo perfectly it's not `404 Error!`.
I think the problem is related to `tomcat8` because the app worked fine on `tomcat7`.. what should i do to solve the problem ?

Comment: Make sure you deploy on `/`, not on `/my-app/`, also please explain why you're claiming that a png file has a mime-type of `image/x-icon`. And last, but not least, hit F12 and check what requests your browser sends and what the results are (naturally, with regards to your icon)

Comment: I have discovered that this problem is only on Firefox what should i do to solve it ?

Comment: Same as above...

Comment: I deployed my app on / and removed the "image/x-icon" ... and still the same.

Comment: try with tomcat9

Answer (score 0):

With all the comments: Works for me (tried on 8.0.32).

Make sure

- that the Icon is indeed available where you expect it
- that the other browsers didn't cache the image
- that you don't have a `<base>` tag in `<html><head>`, so that the browser would expect the image somewhere else than you.

You can use the developer tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>) and check what file Firefox is loading, its response code and content and response headers.

You might need <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Reload in order to bypass the cache, or explicitly flush the cache before this operation.

You can also experiment with temporarily declaring other images and double check on all browsers, just to make sure you're indeed bypassing the cache.